# Flutter: how to add several filters to a List and show the new results

Tags: dart, flutter

I started learning Flutter trying to make my first app. I don't have a developper's background, so I'm trying to learn everything by doin' it. 
My app is receiving some user's data from a json file (name, surname, country, level, ...) and show the whole list of user's name and by tapping on a name a second page opens where you get all the details.
What I'd like to do now is to add a "settings page", where the user can filter, using two dropboxes, the country and/or the level.

If none of the dropboxes are selected the first page should show the whole list of persons by every country and from every level (as it does now), otherwise the list should be filtered to show only the persons from the country selected and only for the level selected.

I just need a hint about what to look for and study in order to realize it. Is my actual approach for the app ok?

Thanks alot for any kind of help. 
Diego

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

//import pages
import './contactdetails.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'USDDN EU Judges',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'USDDN EU Judges'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<User>> _getUser() async {
    var data = await http.get(
        "https://www.disconnecteddog.com/home/json/usddneujudgesdatabase.json");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user = User(
          u["Index"],
          u["Name"],
          u["Country"],
          u["Level"],
          u["Inthesportsince"],
          u["Active"],
          u["English"],
          u["Email"],
          u["Picture"]);
      users.add(user);
    }

    print(users.length);
    return users;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          //
          IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.filter_list, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: null)
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUser(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                  child: Center(child: Text("Loading judges database...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].picture),
                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    subtitle: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Level: "),
                        Text(snapshot.data[index].level),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final int index;
  final String name;
  final String country;
  final String level;
  final String inthesportsince;
  final String active;
  final String english;
  final String email;
  final String picture;

  User(this.index, this.name, this.country, this.level, this.inthesportsince,
      this.active, this.english, this.email, this.picture);
}
```

Contactdetails.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:usddn_judges/main.dart';

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(user.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        //height: 120.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 5.0),
          child: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.account_box,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: new Text(
                    user.name,
                    style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.map,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("Country:  "),
                      new Text(
                        user.country,
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.multiline_chart,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("Level:  "),
                      new Text(
                        user.level,
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.language,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("English:  "),
                      new Text(
                        user.english,
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.flash_on,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("Active:  "),
                      new Text(
                        user.active,
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(color: Colors.blue),
                new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.event,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 26.0,
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("In the sport since:  "),
                      new Text(
                        user.inthesportsince,
                        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Main Contact List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOERv.png)

[Details Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHXPq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into List.where().

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html

By this you can filter your users based on the values within the filter.

```
users.where((user) => user.country == selectedCountry);
```

This is just an example, null handling and a smarter where clause is probably necessary.

I hope this will help you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Screen for filters, lets name it as `FilterScreen`. Then, you can use any state management framework (provider, BloC etc.) to store the filters that user entered in the `FilterScreen`. After returning the search screen, if there is any filter entered requery the list.